# What does this JS do?

Tags: javascript

```
var passwordArray = pwd.replace(/\s+/g, '').split(/\s*/);
```

I found the above line of code is a rather poorly documented JavaScript file, and I don't know exactly what it does. I think it splits a string into an array of characters, similar to PHP's str_split. Am I correct, and if so, is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it replaces any spaces from the password and then it splits the password into an array of characters.

It is a bit redundant to convert a string into an array of characters,because you can already access the characters of a string through brackets(.. not in older IE :( ) or through the string method "charAt" :

```
var a = "abcdefg";
alert(a[3]);//"d"
alert(a.charAt(1));//"b"
```

Comment: how can it do splits with \s* if all the \s are removed before?

Comment: @duedl0r the `\\s*` provides a 0 width match

Comment: @duedl0r the * means 0 or more so you basically are splitting on whitespace of length 0

Comment: well, the star matches as many elements as it can, but it also matches none (0 elements) :  ab*c matches "ac" , "abc" , "abbc" , "abb...bbc" and so on

Comment: I got rid of those two lines, and changed the loop after it to use the string directly. I saw no reason that whitespace actually needed to be removed.

Comment: older versions of IE cannot handle string[index], so you should use string.charAt(index) for safety.

Answer (score 1):

It does the same as: `pwd.split(/\s*/)`.

`pwd.replace(/\s+/g, '').split(/\s*/)` removes all whitespace (tab, space, lfcr etc.) and split the remainder (the string that is returned from the `replace` operation) into an array of characters. The `split(/\s*/)` portion is strange and obsolete, because there shouldn't be any whitespace (`\s`) left in `pwd`.

Hence `pwd.split(/\s*/)` should be sufficient. So:

```
'hello cruel\nworld\t how are you?'.split(/\s*/)
// prints in alert: h,e,l,l,o,c,r,u,e,l,w,o,r,l,d,h,o,w,a,r,e,y,o,u,?
```

as will

```
'hello cruel\nworld\t how are you?'.replace(/\s+/g, '').split(/\s*/)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `replace` portion is removing all white space from the password.  The `\\s+` atom matches non-zero length white spcace.  The 'g' portion matches all instances of the white space and they are all replaced with an empty string.